the numbers in the confusion matrix on girdsearchcv with refit=accuracy do not match the mean accuracy
I applied a GridSearchCV and used multiple metrics, I used the parameter refit='accuracy' for my results.
since refit will try to refit the entire data, confusion matrix or even AUC graph on every fold are not meaningful here.
when i use the entire dataset and generate the confusion matrix, the numbers do not match the mean accuracy that i got from training the model.
 scoring = {'Accuracy':'accuracy','AUC': 'roc_auc'}
 CV = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 4, random_state = None, shuffle=True)

    pipe = Pipeline([('transform', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')), 
    ('kbest', SelectKBest(f_classif)), 
    ('classifier', SVC())]) 


    search = GridSearchCV(
        estimator = pipe,
        param_grid = param_grid,
        refit= 'Accuracy',
        n_jobs=-1,
        scoring=scoring,
        cv=CV,
        verbose=0,
        error_score='raise'
    )
    search.fit(X, y)

    df=pd.DataFrame(search.cv_results_)
    df=df.sort_values('rank_test_Accuracy')
    val_acc = df['mean_test_Accuracy'].iloc[0]
    

and
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
y_pred = results.best_estimator_.predict(X)
print (confusion_matrix(y, y_pred))

when i get the accuracy from TP+ TN / total I don't get the same value of val_acc
not sure if i'm missing anything here

They shouldn't be the same.
